# How to use the ISU thousands separator (space)?

Tags: language-support, system-language

I have the Regional Formats set to "English (Ireland)" in my home system. However, this produces numbers with a coma as a thousand separator in all programmes dependent on this setting, e.g.:

> 1,234,567.89

Ireland (as most other countries in the world) is a signatory to the International System of Units. Therefore [the thousands separator should be the space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules), e.g.:

> 1 234 567.89

How can I change the thousands separator to a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any locale in Ubuntu which combines space as the thousands separator and dot as the decimal point. Maybe you want to [file a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?component=localedata&product=glibc) about it.

Anyway, you can fix it for yourself by modifying the en_IE locale. As regards the `LC_NUMERIC` data it copies them from the en_GB locale, so one way to fix it is to edit the en_GB locale definition file and regenerate the Irish locale:

```
sudo sed -ri 's/^(thousands_sep +)"<U002C>"/\1"<U0020>"/' /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB
sudo locale-gen en_IE.UTF-8
```

Comment: This indeed changes the thousands separator in the Regional Formats menu. However, Calc is ignoring it.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: Yeah, LibreOffice has its own set of locales, unfortunately. Think you'd need to build LO yourself to change it there...